# C#- Select specific items from a list based on partial intersection with another list (Linq + Lambda)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have two lists:

```
List<objA> list1
List<objB> list2

class objA
{
   string Name;
}

class objB
{
   string Name;
   bool SomeProp;
}
```

Using C# linq/lambda I want to select all the objA objects which has their Name property equals to the name property of the second obj (list1.Name == list2.Name) and check another property of objB (list2.SomeProp == true).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend to use join:

```
from a in list1
join b in list2 on a.Name equals b.Name
where b.SomeProp
select a
```

Lambda syntax:

```
list1.Join(listb.Where(b => b.SomeProp),
           a => a.Name, b => b.Name, (a,b) => a)
```

NOTE: Thus you will avoid enumerating list2 collection for each item in list1 (solution with `Any`)

---

To show difference between two solutions - lets see what they look like after translating linq to plain loops. First is

```
list1.Where(a => list2.Any(b => b.Name == a.Name && b.SomeProp))
```

It is equivalent to

```
foreach(var a in list1)
{
   foreach(var b in list2)
   {
       if (a.Name == b.Name && b.SomeProp)
       {
           yield return a;
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

As you can see - it has nested loop, and complexity is O(N*M). With join we have Lookup created for inner sequence:

```
Lookup<string, objB> lookup = list2.Where(b => b.SomeProp).ToLookup(b => b.Name);

foreach(var a in list1)
{
    Grouping<string, objB> g = lookup.GetGrouping(a.Name);
    if (g == null)
       continue;

    foreach(var b in g)
       yield return a;
}
```

Difference here is searching in lookup - which is O(1) operation. Total complexity will be O(M +N)

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
list1.Where(a => list2.Any(b => b.Name == a.Name && b.SomeProp));
```